# Adding a new Support Library to frameworks/support in the AOSP

Tags: android, gradle, build, compilation, androidx

I am trying to add a new Support Library to the AOSP. I assumed since AndroidX came out I may as well try to make a new one inside AOSP/framework/support where all the other AndroidX Support Library's live. The problem I am running into is when I try to add a new folder there with new classes it never compiles it. I even changed code inside framework/support/car and it still never sees it. I was wondering how I can re-build all the AndroidX folder (or just 1).